# Azure App Insights analytics, operations without specific trace

Tags: azure, count, group-by, azure-application-insights

**TL;DR;**
I want to know how many unique "operations_id" with a specific "Operation_Name" that do not have a specific trace message.

**Long Version**
My app traces cache misses to ms azure application insights.
Right now, i'm using a static window (5 min) for cache duration.

I want to evaluate the effectiveness of the cache so I need to know how many times I hit the cache for each miss. More specifically I want to know this proportion for a given operation: "POST MyController/MyAction".

This operation logs the same cadence of traces, but not the same number (depending on the result set, something between 1 to 11 extras messages are logged) except when there's a cache miss, which causes the "Cache miss" trace to pop...

So, basically what i need is to count the number of operations id that does not contains a trace message with value "Cache miss". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so what we need to do is mark each trace line as having or not having the cache miss trace line using `project` and then `summarize` the sum of those indicators by session ID.
From there it's just a matter of joining those indicators with requests with the required name by sessions ID, so:

```
traces 
| project session_Id, isCacheMiss = iff(message contains "Cache miss", 1, 0)
| summarize sum(isCacheMiss) by session_Id
| project session_Id, isCacheMiss = sum_isCacheMiss > 0
| join (
    requests
    | where name == "POST MyController/MyAction"
    | project session_Id  
) on session_Id 
| summarize count() by isCacheMiss
```

Comment: I up voted and down voted only so i could up vote again